# How can I draw a banner at the top of a UIImageView in Obj C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, drawrect

**Some Context**

I am creating a feature that enables the users to share some Images from my App to their Facebook/Twitter account.

The feature works, I implemented the IBAction and I can share some Images within Facebook and Twitter.

**The Issue**

My company's marketing department is now asking me to add at the top of the shared images, a banner with the company's logo and the date.

This is what I have to display :

[image]

For now I only share the white rectangle. Now I have to add this banner, the blue rectangle.

**My Thoughts**

I was wondering how I will be developing it. First of all I was thinking about drawing it programmatically within a view.

```
UIView *banner  = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 35, self.view.frame.size.width, 60)];
banner.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
[self.view addSubview:banner];
```

The problem is I really don't know how to make it resizable in order to fit all the different screen sizes. But also, how to add the logo within this rectangle, the label date and finally, how can I fit it in my shared UIImage

Then I was wondering, "maybe I can draw it like in Android, directly in the XML file". But from all my investigations, it looks easier to do it programmatically.

**Help needed**

I would appreciate some advices in order to focus myself on a better way to develop it, because right now my ideas are kind of fuzzy.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: So what you want exactly, want to draw the logo on the Image on the banner image (Core redrawing image so that  the image will have the logo and banner image) . Or trying add logo on image View.

Comment: I have edited my question with a fast graphical representation so that you can understand my needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in this way

Consider the img1 is the image which you get from URL.
Here I have taken a bannerView, You can add the label and image into it.

Code :

```
UIImage *img1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Screen.png"];

//Only banner view, on which we will design the label and logo
UIView *vwBanner = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, img1.size.width, 60)];
vwBanner.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

//Logo design
UIImageView *imgVwLogo = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(CGRectGetWidth(vwBanner.frame) - 100 , 0, 100, 100)];
imgVwLogo.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[vwBanner addSubview:imgVwLogo];

//Label design
UILabel *lbl = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 0, CGRectGetWidth(vwBanner.frame) - imgVwLogo.frame.size.width, CGRectGetHeight(vwBanner.frame))];
lbl.text = @"Thurseday, 20 October 2016";
[vwBanner addSubview:lbl];


//Full view which contains the downloaded image and banner image
UIView *vwWithBanner = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, img1.size.width, img1.size.height+vwBanner.frame.size.height)];
[vwWithBanner addSubview:vwBanner];

//imageView with downloaded image 
UIImageView *imgVw = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, CGRectGetMaxY(vwBanner.frame), img1.size.width, img1.size.height)];
imgVw.image = img1;
[vwWithBanner addSubview:imgVw];

//Draw the image of full view
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(vwWithBanner.bounds.size, NO, img1.scale);
[vwWithBanner drawViewHierarchyInRect:vwWithBanner.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];

UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Output :

[image: Updated image]

See the gray bar is the Banner View and the below is the image. I did not have image so taken a screen shot of simulator to demonstrate the example.

Comment: This is exactly what I was asking. I will accept this answer because it will help me going further. Thank you to @Aneesh also.

Comment: But is it possible to create a new view with the image and the banner so that the banner isn't ON the Image, but above the image?

Comment: Yes, That is what I have demonstrated here. The vwBanner is above the imageView. In my case the grey one is the added image. I have added the background color of View as grey, when ever you put image on it and then take the image, it will come as you want.

Comment: See I have updated the answer mostly similar to your requirement.

Comment: You're right, I thought it wasn't above, but it is. Thank you. I will begin working on adding the date and the logo.

Comment: Glad to hear it helped you.

Comment: Are you kidding me? It's awesome Sir! Thank you life saver :)

Answer (score 1):

```
 UIView *banner  = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 35, self.view.frame.size.width, 60)];
banner.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];


UIImageView *imgBanner=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, banner.frame.size.width, banner.frame.size.height)];
    [imgBanner setImage:@"img.png"];
     imgBanner.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

[banner addSubView:imgBanner];
[self.view addSubview:banner];
```

Answer (score 1):

Call this method once you get the image,

```
UIImage *img = [self drawText:@"Some text"
                            inImage:img 
                            atPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
```

Function implementation like this,

```
+(UIImage*) drawText:(NSString*) text 
             inImage:(UIImage*)  image 
             atPoint:(CGPoint)   point 
{

UIFont *font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12];
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.size);
[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,image.size.width,image.size.height)];
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(point.x, point.y, image.size.width, image.size.height);
[[UIColor whiteColor] set];
[text drawInRect:CGRectIntegral(rect) withFont:font]; 
UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

return newImage;
```

}

Comment: I never mentioned taking a photo. I'm only sharing some images from my Application that I retrieve from a server.

Comment: so you will be getting image from server to your class method right?

Comment: Yes, I have an URL, and I can get my image from it. I'm currently sharing this image to Facebook/Twitter. Now I only need to add a banner (the blue rectangle), that I have to draw my self and "position it" at the top or create a new image composed of the 2 images.

Comment: But I don't need the imagePickerController right? So what I do for this [(UIImage *)[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];

Comment: @Funnybear have you checked the updated answer , which includes only one method which will be calling from your response after getting the image.

Comment: Yes, I'm testing it, thank you. I will keep you informed

Comment: OK, it's working, I can draw some text on my Image, it's nice. But I would like to draw something outside my image, to not hide some part of it. But I can begin working in this way. Thank you